What does "Look out, old ferret!" mean?
In An Uncomfortable Bed by Guy de Maupassant, a cautious narrator visits a chateau with prank-loving friends and becomes overly suspicious of their intentions.

My friends were fond of practical jokes, and now and then, they did have a great time playing those jokes on me. Also, I do not care to know people who are not.
When I arrived, they gave me a princely reception, which at once awakened suspicion in my mind.
They fired off rifles, embraced me, made much of me, as if they expected to have great fun at my expense.
I said to myself:
"Look out, old ferret! They have something in store for you."

The Oxford dictionary says.
Ferret:.
a domesticated polecat used chiefly for catching rabbits. It is typically albino in coloration, but sometimes brown.
What does "Look out, old ferret!" mean?
Who is referred to as 'an old ferret,' and why does the narrator use this term?

In the early 20th century the slang of the young upper class in Britain included calling each other "old something" as a friendly form of address. "Old bean is the best known, but I've certainly heard variants. This may be one of them.

Note that de Maupassant was French - the translator chose the expression.

We had a similar late-ish 20th century slang in tertiary school days in Canada, although 'old' was often followed by something slightly less polite or a reference to a funny-sounding creature such as a "tapir" or "turbot".  "Ferret" has this characteristic. Strictly a verbal form of address between good friends, though I suppose if we'd had texting it might have been used.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany I think "old" means experienced not aged.

@KateBunting It could also be that Maupassant used a French phrase that the translator calqued (translated literally) into English. (Not knowing the original, I have no clue if this is the case or not.)

@JamesMathai I'm not sure you can dissect it like that. It's just a friendly-sounding form of address, perhaps indicating that you've known the person a relatively long time and are comfortable with them. But as a native speaker we don't think of it like that, of course.

He said it to himself he believes he is a wise ferret and he can ferret out what those tricky rabbits are up to. He previously said he cares for those who try to prank him up.

The title of the original (French) version is “La farce.” And the passage you ask about is

je me dis : « Attention, vieux furet, on prépare quelque chose. »

Or, in English,

I said to myself, “Careful, old ferret, they’re preparing something.”

And here, old ferret is a verbatim, word-for-word translation of the French vieux furet. Besides the literal meaning of the animal, furet also has the figurative meaning of someone who is wily or crafty, or of someone who searches thoroughly and carefully.
Of course, that last meaning of French furet is not too dissimilar from our phrasal verb ferret out—both are clearly drawn from the behavior of ferrets.
Thus, in contemporary English we might describe the narrator as suspecting something fishy, or as having his antennæ up. He thinks himself wily enough to have detected that something was going on.
So he’s simultaneously warning and congratulating himself.

And it's not really a great translation at that. It's a bit too literal, since it's not really a common expression in English. A better equivalent might have been "sly old fox".  Using translated books to learn English is probably not a particularly good idea.

As a further illustration of @BillyKerr’s point, consider that the original title, La farce, can mean either  “the prank,” or “the practical joke,” but it could also be translated as “[the practice or art of] pranks.” Yet the translator chose to render it as “An Uncomfortable Bed,”  which is particularly curious because the incident involving the bed is but one of two unrelated pranks that the story recounts.

@PaulTanenbaum It may be because when Albert McMaster et al. translated Maupassant into "The Entire Original Maupassant Short Stories" only the incident about the bed was translated. The incident with Mme Dufour and the "phosphide of lime" is apparently not included.

That makes for an odd interpretation of their title’s entire, wouldn’t you agree, @R.M.? Bowdlerization, I suppose. But in any event, false advertising.

Using sly old fox would collide with foxes being known tricksters or what is the same pranksters and while he enjoys fencing with good pranksters he himself doesn't want to prank.

@PaulTanenbaum Nice. Thanks for the French original version. The idioms are related to an animal's character. A French ferret doesn't behave differently.

Another meaning of ferret is to hunt, just like the ferret hunting for small animals.  The narrator called himself or herself ferret, hunting for clues, trying to find out what pranks his or her friends would play.
(There's an answer in
brainly, but the link asks for logging in and so on.  Ignore it if
you can't find that answer.)
